# How do i connect my .php to phpmyadim?

Tags: php, phpmyadmin

I need help on creating a basic log-in page and registration page. I only know the basic stuff on php. And my boss told me to use the database he created online (phpmyadmin). So how do I connect the .php file I created to the online database? I have experienced connecting it to a database. But not the one that's online. Any help please? Thank you!

Comment: So you want to create a web application of some sort to display and interact with your mysql database built on phpmyadmin?

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, PhpMyAdmin is **not** a database. It is a PHP based database admin tool to ease the management of databases so that you don't need to do the "boring" commandline interface stuff.

Assuming that it's actually just a MySQL database, then you can connect it using [mysql_connect()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php).

Answer (score 0):

if you know how to connect it to the local database, it's always the same: you need a server address (localhost, IP or domain), database name, username and password.

read more here:

- http://php.net/mysqli
- http://php.net/mysql